# Is there a way to reference an anonymous type as a struct member?

Tags: rust, types, async-await

Consider the following Rust code:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
    for _ in 1..10 {
        v.push(wrap_future(Box::pin(async {})));
    }
}

fn wrap_future<T>(a: Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output=T>>>) -> impl Future<Output=T> {
    async {
        println!("doing stuff before awaiting");
        let result=a.await;
        println!("doing stuff after awaiting");
        result
    }
}
```

As you can see, the futures I'm putting into the `Vec` don't need to be boxed, since they are all the same type and the compiler can infer what that type is.

I would like to create a `struct` that has this `Vec<...>` type as one of its members, so that I could add a line at the end of `main()`:

```rust
let thing = MyStruct {myvec: v};
```

without any additional overhead (i.e. boxing).

Type inference and `impl Trait` syntax aren't allowed on struct members, and since the future type returned by an async block exists entirely within the compiler and is exclusive to that exact async block, there's no way to reference it by name.  It seems to me that what I want to do is impossible.  Is it?  If so, will it become possible in a future version of Rust?

I am aware that it would be easy to sidestep this problem by simply boxing all the futures in the `Vec` as I did the argument to `wrap_future()` but I'd prefer not to do this if I can avoid it.

I am well aware that doing this would mean that there could be only one `async` block in my entire codebase whose result values could possibly be added to such a `Vec`, and thus that there could be only one function in my entire codebase that could create values that could possibly be pushed to it.  I am okay with this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I'm stupid.  I forgot that structs could have type parameters.

```rust
struct MyStruct<F> where F: Future<Output=()> {
     myvec: Vec<F>,
}
```

Comment: You don't need the type constraint on the struct. If you need it on some impls, you have to add it there either way, but in the case there is no benefit of having it on the struct definition as well.